# Upload Images through promises , bluebird pass params

Tags: javascript, return, promise, bluebird

I need to upload images on Amazon S3 and to store the image's links received as a response into database. 
I'm using Bluebird.js. Please tell me how to pass the values recorded from one Promise to another.

```
Promise.resolve()
.then(function() {
    var promImageLoc = [];
    var upload = $scope.uploaderPromo.queue;
    $scope.uploaderPromo.uploadAll();
    $scope.uploaderPromo.onSuccessItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.log('success response', response);
        var promImage = promImageLoc.push(response.location);
        return promImage;
    }
    console.log(promImage);
})
.then(function (promImageLoc) {
    console.log(promImageLoc);
})
```

---

Update:  I'm begginer at MEAN stack developer and using `angular-file-upload` and `multer` to pass file from client side to server. All I need (*is love*) now - make entry in mongo DB with follows link. Links come in callback one after another because files are sent one by one (POST) and i have finally entry but with empty arrays. I know the reason of that but I don't know how to solve it. Here is full code of function that sent data from client.

```
$scope.createPromo = function () {
            Promise.resolve()
            .then(function() {
                var promImageLoc = [];
                var upload = $scope.uploaderPromo.queue;
                $scope.uploaderPromo.uploadAll();
                async.eachSeries(upload, function(response) {
                    $scope.uploaderPromo.onSuccessItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
                        console.log('success response', response);
                        return promImageLoc.push(response.location);
                    }
                })
            })
            .then(function() {
                var promLogoLoc = [];
                $scope.uploaderLogo.uploadAll();
                $scope.uploaderLogo.onSuccessItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
                    console.log('success response', response);
                    var location = response.location;
                    return location;
                }
                promLogoLoc.push(location);
                return promLogoLoc;
            })
            .then(function (promImageLoc, promLogoLoc) {
                if ($scope.promZipCode == undefined) {
                    $scope.promZipCode = '07946';
                }
                $http.post("/promo/create", {
                    'promName':     $cookieStore.get('User').user.username + '.' + $scope.promName, //username.promotion name
                    'promDesc':     $scope.promDesc,
                    'promImage':    promImageLoc,
                    'promLock':     $scope.promLock,
                    'promLogo':     promLogoLoc,
                    'promLogoPos':  $scope.selectPos,
                    'promNotice':   $scope.promNotice,
                    'promZipCode':  $scope.promZipCode, //{obj}
                    'promRadius':   $scope.promRadius
                })
                .success(function (data, status) {
                    console.log(status);
                    $state.go('home.promotion.promotions');
                }).error(function (err) {
                    $scope.isUniqError = true;
                    console.log('CREATE ERR', err);
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('ERROR PROMISE:', error);
            })
```

Comment: `return promImageLoc` should suffice, but your actual problem seems to be that this `uploaderPromo` thing doesn't yield a promise.

Comment: @Bergi you right! At first I have an empty array in `console.log()` and only then comes link and it pushes into the array

Comment: I don't know how to make first upload all files on bucket and only then push callback's links into arr and write to DB

Comment: We don't know either. What is this uploader plugin thing you're using, how does it work, how can you promisify it?